# Need help simplifying methods using generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have functions like this one below that loads a database table using LinqToSql and returns a list of the entries converted into my custom model class:

```cs
    public List<AreaModel> LoadListOfAreaModels(Boolean includeDeleted = false)
    {
        using (LinqToSqlDataContext dc = new LinqToSqlDataContext())
        {
            IQueryable<Areas> filtered = includeDeleted
                ? dc.Areas.Where((c) => !c.DataRowDeleted)
                : dc.Areas;
            return filtered.Select((c) => AreaModel.ModelFactoryFromLinq(c)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now I have quite a few tables and all have to get loaded and converted in the same way.

Can I somehow avoid typing this function a dozen times and just changing the `AreaModel` and `Areas` to e.g. `TownModel` and `Towns` by using a generic function?

I already tried this, but failed because I could not find a way to call a static class method if I only have the generic type parameter of it.

Further info: All `XxxModel` classes have the common superclass `ModelBase` (which does not contain the static factory method I need to call though!), all Linq table classes (like `Areas` or `Towns`) implement the common interface `ILinqClass`.

Any ideas on how to implement this the most elegant way?

---

Inspired by **knittl**'s answer, I came up with this solution:

```cs
    public List<TModel> LoadListOfModels<TLinq, TModel>(
        Func<TLinq, bool> filter,
        Func<TLinq, TModel> modelFactory
        )
        where TLinq : class, ILinqClass
        where TModel : ModelBase
    {
        using (LinqToSqlDataContext dc = new LinqToSqlDataContext())
        {
            return dc.GetTable<TLinq>()
                .Where(filter)
                .Select(modelFactory)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `DataRowDeleted` defined in `ModelBase`?

Comment: @Lee Yes, `DataRowDeleted` it's part of an interface `ModelBase` implements

Comment: The problem as you mention is that AreaModel is a static class. Why don't you try to make you AreaModel, TownModel a non static class? Then they can implement an interface, something like IModelFactory with a method ModelFactoryFromLinq and then you can pass an implementation to this interface to your LoadList... method.

Comment: @JordiRuiz AreaModel is not static, and I could not manage to put ModelFactoryFromLinq() to an interface because of the different parameter and return types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass delegates/Funcs:

```
public List<TModel> LoadListOfModels<TDbModel, TModel>(
  Func<LinqToSqlDataContext, TDbModel> modelSelector,
  Func<TDbModel, bool> isDeleted,
  Func<TDbModel, TModel> modelFactory,
  bool includeDeleted = false)
{
    using (LinqToSqlDataContext dc = new LinqToSqlDataContext())
    {
        var models = modelSelector(dc);
        var filtered = includeDeleted
            ? models.Where(c => !isDeleted(c))
            : models;

        return filtered.Select(modelFactory).ToList();
    }
}
```

For `Area` call as follows:

```
 LoadListOfModels(
   dc => dc.Areas,
   c => c.DataRowDeleted,
   Area.ModelFactoryFromLinq,
   includeDeleted);
```

For `Town`:

```
 LoadListOfModels(
   dc => dc.Towns,
   c => c.DataRowDeleted,
   Town.ModelFactoryFromLinq,
   includeDeleted);
```

---

You might even be able to get rid of the `includeDeleted` parameter. Simply pass a filter func `Func<TDbModel, bool> filter`.

```
return modelsSelector(dc)
  .Where(filter)
  .Select(modelFactory)
  .ToList();
```

Call:

```
LoadListOfModels(dc => dc.Areas, c => true, Area.ModelFactoryFromLinq);
LoadListOfModels(dc => dc.Areas, c => !c.DataRowDeleted, Area.ModelFactoryFromLinq);
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get rid of the modelSelector parameter as well, see my edited question for my final approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    public bool DataRowDeleted { get; set; }
    public abstract TModel ModelFactoryFromLinq();
}

public class Area : BaseClass<AreaModel>
{
    public override AreaModel ModelFactoryFromLinq()
    {
        return new AreaModel();
    }
}

public static List<TModel> LoadListOfAreaModels<TContext, TModel>(bool includeDeleted = false)
    where TContext : BaseClass<TModel>, new()
    where TModel : class
{
    using (var dc = new LinqToSqlDataContext())
    {
        IQueryable<TContext> filtered = includeDeleted
            ? dc.GetTable<TContext>().Where((c) => !c.DataRowDeleted)
            : dc.GetTable<TContext>();
        return filtered.Select((c) => c.ModelFactoryFromLinq()).ToList();
    }
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
List<AreaModel> result = SomeClassName.LoadListOfAreaModels<Area, AreaModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `DataRowDeleted` is defined in `ModelBase` you should be able to do:

```
public static IQueryable<TModel> LoadListOfQuery<T, TModel>(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TModel>> selector, bool includeDeleted = false) where T : ModelBase {
    IQueryable<T> filtered = includeDeleted ? source : source.Where(s => !s.DataRowDeleted);
    return filtered.Select(selector);
}
```

Then add a function to evaluate a query given a context:

```
public static List<T> ExecList(Func<LinqToSqlDataContext, IQueryable<T>> qf)
{
    using(var c = new LinqToSqlDataContext())
    {
         var q = qf(c);
         return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
public List<AreaModel> LoadListOfAreaModels(bool includeDeleted = false)
{
    ExecList(c => LoadListOfQuery(c.Areas, a => AreaModel.ModelFactoryFromLinq(a), includeDeleted);
}
```